# android screen orientation change issue

Tags: android, orientation

I have this in onCreate:

```
System.out.println("orientation: " + getResources().getConfiguration().orientation);
```

The results are:

Real orientation:    Output:

```
portrait............portrait  
landscape...........landscape  
portrait............landscape  
landscape...........landscape
```

Can anyone tell me why after landscape orientation portrait orientation doesns't apply? I am using Android OS 2.3.6.

Comment: Maybe I'm insane, but I don't see how that `println` can produce those results. `"orientation:"` is not even in the output.

Comment: @Eric output is "orientation: 1" but instead of this I have written "portrait". How this is related to issue?

Comment: Because each line of your output has two orientations on it. Your output would only have one orientation per line. I'm trying to understand what order these are coming in and how you are triggering the orientation changes.

Comment: orientation: 1 - portrait
orientation: 2 - landscape

Comment: So, those two outputs would indicate that the screen was vertical, then turned on its side. What are you having difficulty understanding?

Comment: please, read one more time my post

Comment: moderator's edited my post incorrectly :)